# XSLT как реализовать 2 вида

Tags: xml, xslt

есть 2 файла XML оч оч оч похожих, но отличается незначительно, а именно в версии пространства имен

1 файл

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ulv3.xslt" ?>
<ns1:FNSVipULResponse
    xmlns:ns1="urn://x-artefacts-fns-vipul-tosmv-ru/311-14/4.0.5"
    ИдДок="AC9099FF-FD00-4EDB-A55D-30D656FB2293">
  <ns1:СвЮЛ>
    версия 4.0.5
  </ns1:СвЮЛ>
</ns1:FNSVipULResponse>
```

2 файл

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ulv3.xslt" ?>
<ns1:FNSVipULResponse
    xmlns:ns1="urn://x-artefacts-fns-vipul-tosmv-ru/311-14/4.0.6" <!-- отличие тут!  -->
    ИдДок="8397C31E-9A30-455A-9073-7CF531FB1F0C">
  <ns1:СвЮЛ>
    версия 4.0.6
  </ns1:СвЮЛ>
</ns1:FNSVipULResponse>
```

отличие в ns1 - разная версия пространства имен

а есть шаблон XSLT который корректно обрабатывает 1й файл:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns1="urn://x-artefacts-fns-vipul-tosmv-ru/311-14/4.0.5">
  <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="ns1:FNSVipULResponse">
    <b>ТЕКСТ = </b>
    <xsl:value-of select="./ns1:СвЮЛ"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

как сделать так чтобы он также обрабатывал 2й файл, вносить изменения в XML нельзя, только в шаблон
тоесть если я во 2м файле вместо 4.0.6 напишу 4.0.5 - то все заработает сразу. но изменять XML нельзя, как можно обойтись средствами шаблона чтоб не сильно его переписывать, чтобы понимал обе версии?
можно как то отключить эти пространства имен, чтобы он оба понимал?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете матчить по локальным именам с помощью функции `local-name()`:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/*[local-name() = 'FNSVipULResponse']">
    <b>ТЕКСТ = <xsl:value-of select="./*[local-name() = 'СвЮЛ']"/></b>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Либо просто `name() = 'ns1:СвЮЛ'`, если хотите более надёжный матч.

Comment: ок. а еще вариантов нет? может как то отключить пространства имен, сделать чтобы как то без ns1 обращаться?

Comment: Можете либо написать ещё одно преобразование, которое удаляет их, и пропускать документ два раза, либо написать sed-скрипт, который удаляет их в тексте. [Большой СО](https://stackoverflow.com/a/512627/1892060) тоже за препроцессинг.

Comment: что за еще одно преобразование? можно как то через xslt удалить?

Comment: А можно как то переназначить пространство имен? ns1  ???

Comment: Я же вам уже написал. Сделайте маленькое преобразование, которое просто заменяет новую версию на старую, а уже результат этого преобразования кормите вашему изначальному. Это же элементарный "конвеер".